# Wordpress: return do_action('deposit_redirect');

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am modifying the functionality of a Wordpress theme that someone has bought and is using.

I myself don't usually work with Wordpress, so don't know much about how it's core functionality works.

I have found that WP_Error() is defined by a class in Wordpress itself.

The theme I am modifying, returns the following statement (in php):

```
return new WP_Error( 'not_enough', __( "Your credit is not enough to perform this transaction.", "boxtheme" ) );
```

I would like to replace this, with a redirect. Instead of a popup firing, I would like for the page to be taken to a credits deposit page / specific url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

So is it possible to perform something like this?

```
return do_action('deposit_redirect');
```

or

```
return new do_action('deposit_redirect');
```

I'd much rather build the entire platform from the ground up, but I am modifying this instead.